# remove the nth value from a doubly linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

oldVal() method this will get to the correct if, else-if, or else statement that is needed to remove the node but then I always get a null point exception I have compared this to similar codes and cannot seem to find what is wrong with it.

please help:

```
enter code here//    ***************************************************************
// DoubleLinked.java
//
// A class using a doubly linked list to represent a list of integers.
//
// ***************************************************************
public class DoubleLinked
{
private int size=0;
private IntNode list;
// ----------------------------------------------
// Constructor -- initializes list
// ----------------------------------------------
public DoubleLinked()
{
    list = null;
}
// ----------------------------------------------
// Prints the list elements
// ----------------------------------------------
public void print()
{
    for (IntNode temp = list; temp != null; temp = temp.next)
        System.out.println(temp.val);
}
// ----------------------------------------------
// Adds new element to front of list
// ----------------------------------------------
public void addToFront(int val)
{
    IntNode newNode = new IntNode(val);
    newNode.next = list;
    if (list != null)
        list.prev = newNode;
    list = newNode;
    size++;
}

public void addToEnd(int val)
{

    IntNode newNode = new IntNode(val);
    IntNode current;
    if (list == null)
        {list= newNode;}
    else
    {
        current=list;
        while(current.next != null)
            current = current.next;
        current.next = newNode;

    }
    size++;
}

public void removeFirst()
{
    IntNode test = list;

    if (test == null){System.out.println("your list is emty"); size++;}


    else if (list != null) { // list might be empty
        IntNode temp = list.prev;

            if(list.next==null && list.prev==null) {
                list=null;



            }
            else {
                list.next.prev = null;
                list = list.next;
            }
        }

size--;
    }


public void removeLast()
{
IntNode test = list;


    if (test == null){System.out.println("your list is emty");       size++;}

    else if(list.next==null && list.prev==null) 
    {
        list=null;
         }

    else if (list != null){
        IntNode current=list;
        while(current.next.next != null)
            current = current.next;
        current.next=null;
    }

size--;
}


    public void oldVal(int val)
    {
        IntNode temp=list;
          for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
          {

              if (temp.val != val)
                temp= temp.next;
              else{

                   if  (temp.prev == null)
                    {    

                      list=list.next;
                    }
                  if (temp.next == null)
                    {    

                      temp.prev.next=null;
                    }
                  else
                  {

                     temp.prev.next=temp.next;
                     temp.next.prev=temp.prev;
                  }
                  size--;
                  break;
              }


        }}

//***************************************************************
// An inner class that represents a list element.
//***************************************************************
class IntNode
{
    public int val;
    public IntNode next;
    public IntNode prev;
    public IntNode(int val)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }
}}
```

Comment: have you inserted any element before trying to remove nth element? show the method to insert

Comment: Why do you increment the size of the data structure when test == null in the removeFirst method?  When the size attribute is inaccurate, your other code will likely fail.

Comment: because that means it will not edit the list at all so the size++ is there in order to cancel out the size-- at the end of the method.

Comment: Also, if this is a doubly linked list, you may want to assign "current" to newNode.prev in your addToEnd method